# What is CASlotProxy?

Tags: iphone, uiview

Anyone have any idea about CASlotProxy Class in Cocoa (iOS SDK)? I found it in UIView contents.

Comment: You mean Cocoa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another undocumented class, as a proxy to an internal C++ rendering object in QuartzCore.

The interface is like http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/QuartzCore/CASlotProxy.h.

Comment: I see that, Is there anyway to pull any raw image from it ?

Comment: Yes, I did but black image coming :(